# How to calculate $\lim _{x\to \infty} x^2\int _0 ^x e^{t^3-x^3}dt $

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $$\lim _{x\to \infty}  x^2\int _0 ^x e^{t^3-x^3}dt $$ I think  $e^{t^3} $ is doesnt have an elenentary antiderivative so Fundamental theorem of calculus is to be used . But its in product with $x^2$ and also its not an indeterminate form so I dont know what to do?

Comment: Of course $\;e^{t^3}\;$ is Riemann integrable in any bounded interval as that's a *continuous* function...

Comment: Badically that was asked in an exam for grade 12 so ... also  I dont know what Riemann sum is and is it necessary to solve it , hope for this sum we have another elementary approach

Comment: What's the solution? I seem to get $\;\frac13\;$ but I'm using the Fundamental theorem and l'Hospital...not sure whether that's fine.

Comment: Yup thats write can you post it (it was mcq so L hospital ) is allowed

Comment: As DonAntonio says, you don't mean "not integrable." You mean "doesn't have an elementary antiderivative."

Comment: Ya ill edit....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $\;\int e^{t^3}dt=F(t)\;$ , so

$$x^2\int_0^x e^{t^3-x^3}dt=\frac{x^2}{e^{x^3}}\left(F(x)-F(0)\right)$$

and now apply l'Hospital (why can we?):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2F(x)}{e^{x^3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2F(x)+x^2e^{x^3}}{3x^2e^{x^3}}=\frac13$$

Answer (score 7):

Hint. Note that
$$x^2\int _0 ^x e^{t^3-x^3}dt=\frac{\int _0 ^x e^{t^3}dt}{e^{x^3}/x^2}$$
and both numerator and denominator go to infinity as $x\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\int_0^x e^{t^3}dt=-\frac{x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-x^3\right)}{3
   \sqrt[3]{-x^3}}-(-1)^{2/3} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$
So you have:
$$y(x)=-\frac{x^2}{e^{x^3}}\left[\frac{x \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-x^3\right)}{3
   \sqrt[3]{-x^3}}+(-1)^{2/3} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \right]$$
For $x \rightarrow+\infty$ we have: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty}y(x)=\frac{1}{3}$$